# BI Answers COUNT the number in cloumn?

Tags: obiee, oracle-bi

Here is the data look like.

```
Name    P_ID    NUM
 A       P1      3
 A       P2      1
 B       P3      1
 B       P4      1
 C       P5      2
 D       P7      1
```

In BI Answers I want the result show like this:

```
Name    NUM_OF_1    NUM_OF_2    NUM_OF_3    SUM
 A         1           0           1         2
 B         2           0           0         2
 C         0           1           0         1
 D         1           0           0         1
```

The column NUM_OF_N is occurrences of a number in a 'name' group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a SQL query then you can try the following pivot:

```
SELECT Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NUM = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUM_OF_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NUM = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUM_OF_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NUM = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUM_OF_3,
       COUNT(*) AS "SUM"
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim has got it nailed in terms of SQL. In terms of pure OBI dev you should put that logic into logical (measure) columns in your RPD though so the BI server treats them as such and you can use them automatically with all the usual functionalities like drill, aggregate etc